# A word to describe someone who does not question things?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

It's not about indifference or apathy to the world but about people who just do what they are told, never question why they should do that.

Comment: Please show us how you'd like to use the word, with a sample sentence.  Hopefully then your question would be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

[***docile***](https://www.google.co.in/#q=docile+meaning)

> adjective: **docile**:
>
> ready to accept control or instruction; submissive.
>
> "a cheap and docile workforce"
>
> synonyms:  compliant, obedient, pliant, dutiful, willing, passive, submissive, deferential, tame, meek, mild, lamblike, unassertive, unresisting, yielding, cooperative, amenable, accommodating, biddable, persuadable, ductile, manageable, controllable, tractable, malleable, manipulable, easily manipulated, easily handled, like putty in one's hands;
> (from [Google](https://www.google.co.in/#q=docile+meaning))

Answer (score 3):

You've nearly answered your own question, as the word ***[unquestioning](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unquestioning)*** conveys exactly what you describe:

> Accepting something without dissent or doubt.

Answer (score 2):

That type of person can be described as a **Yes-man**:

> #### Yes-man
>
> 1. A person who agrees with everything that is said.
> 2. One who endorses or supports, without criticism, every opinion or proposal of an associate or superior.

Answer (score 1):

People who do what they're told without questioning why are sometimes referred to as **Sheep**: [an easily led person.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sheep)

Answer (score 0):

That person is *Obedient*

> **Obedient** -
>   Dutifully complying with the commands, orders, or instructions of one in authority.
>   http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obedient

Answer (score 0):

If you want to emphasize the "do what they're told" aspect, you could say "subservient"